# All folders open with VS Code Directly

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Whenever I do double click on any folder, it opens in VS Code. While it should be opened in File Explorer. How can I change settings in Windows 8.1?

I followed instructions given by a website but I could not find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the file, select Open with, and then click the option at the very bottom of the submenu. This will be Choose default program in Windows 8.

In the resulting dialog box, make sure that the option for changing the default is checked.

Source: [Set which program opens when you double-click a file](https://www.pcworld.com/article/420123/control-what-program-opens-when-you-double-click-a-file.html#:%7E:text=Right%2Dclick%20the%20file%2C%20select,changing%20the%20default%20is%20checked.)

Comment: Also, I would highly encourage you to upgrade to Windows 11 from Windows 8